# Ошибка в python socket: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, сокет

При подключении с клиента и отправке каких-то данных с него - возникает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\newaz.py", line 35, in <module>
    buf = conn.recv(64)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Как это исправить? Код сервера:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
HOST = ''  # this is your localhost
PORT = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
# socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
# socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
print(
'socket created')

# Bind socket to Host and Port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print(
    'Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1])

print(
'Socket Bind Success!')

# listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
s.listen(10)
print(
'Socket is now listening')

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    time.sleep(3)
    conn.send(str.encode("WOOOOOOOORLD!"))
    print(
    'Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    buf = conn.recv(64)
    print(
    buf)
s.close()
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket

try:
     conn = socket.socket()
     conn.connect( ("127.0.0.1", 8080) )
     conn.setblocking(0)
     conn.send(str.encode("I'am connected!"))
except socket.error:
     print(socket.error)
     if socket.error:
          print("Connection error")
```

Comment: попробуйте в сокет отправлять байты - `conn.send(b'hello')`

Comment: Та же самая ошибка

Comment: У меня норм все запускается, попробуйте порт поменять

Comment: Странно, но почему-то опять эта же ошибка. P.S Она появляется лишь тогда, когда клиент подключается к серверу и отправляет что-то

Comment: Пропишите четко `host` на сервере - `'127.0.0.1'` как на клиенте

Comment: Тоже самое. Но интересно то, что в PythonIDLE - эта ошибка есть, а в  PyCharm - нет. Вообще не пойму в чём дело.

Comment: приведите полный traceback. У вас сервер пытается что-то клиенту подключившемуся отправить, но в клиенте не видно, где вы читаете.

Comment: Добавил Traceback в вопрос

Comment: куда вы думаете `conn.sendall(b"WOOOOOOOORLD!")` пишет? И кто это читает и в каком коде?